# Rails button_to a external link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with a field of URL generated by users now I want in the show page to get access to thise external URL by clicking in a button in the normal situation where the link have a path i am doing a code like this `<%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path, class: "btn sign-home-btn" %>`, but here the links are generated by users and are external

Answer (score 0):

Put the url address in the second argument of the link_to. Like so:

```
<%= link_to 'External Url', @external_url, class: "btn sign-home-btn" %>
```

The link_to method just creates the html for a link. The path can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: with this method I am redirected to a URL like this http://localhost:3000/pages/www.externalurl.com

Comment: The external url needs to have have "http://" or "https://" at the front of it. Otherwise it assumes a local path.